# Validations with custom message and no attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

Ruby on Rails 4.1

The form has validations checked in the model. I have custom messages that are showing the attribute name before the message.

I am trying to specify the translation of the attribute in the en.yml file OR just remove the attribute name. I am not getting an error but it is only humanizing the attributes without a custom message.

Example, one message I get is `* Cc name your name on the credit card cannot be blank`, I want it to say `Your name on the credit card cannot be blank` OR `Credit card name cannot be blank`.

Model:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

validates_presence_of :telephone, :email, :address1, :city, :state, :postal_code, :country, :cc_type, :cc_number, :ccv, :expires_on, :ship_name, :ship_address1, :ship_city, :ship_state, :ship_postal_code, :ship_country

validates_presence_of :cc_name, 
:message => ' Your name on the credit card cannot be blank'

validates_presence_of :name_auth, 
:message => ' Your name authorizing the purchase cannot be blank'
```

The error message file:

```
<% if @payment.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        The form contains <%= pluralize(@payment.errors.count, "error") %>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <% @payment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li>* <%= msg.humanize %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The en.yml file:

```
en:
activerecord:
attributes:
  cc_name: "Credit card name"
  name_auth: "Authorizing name"
  date_auth: "Authorized date"
  card_holder_auth: "Authorized card holder"
  charge_auth: "Authorizing payment"
  cc_number: "Credit card number" 
  ccv: "Card code verification (CCV)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after way too much time I figured out that the best answer should be to set the format of the errors. Who wants the attribute name in the error? I could easily add it, and who actually names their attributes what thay want the end use to see? Anyway this re-formats the error messages:

```
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
```

The default is "%{attribute} %{message}", which IMO is normally not wanted and should be changed.

Comment: Sure wish I could scope this to certain activerecord models instead of everything.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to put the error message into en.yml as follows:

```
en:
 activerecord:
   errors:
     models:
       payment:
         attributes:
          cc_name:
            blank: "Credit card name cannot be blank"
```

Then you can remove the custom message in the model.

Comment: I just tried this, it is placing the #{attribute_name} then the blank message. * Cc name credit card name cannot be blank,  with your code. :/